# Table Testing Go Generics

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, generics

I'm excited for Go 1.18 and wanted to test the new generics feature.
Feels pretty neat to use, but I stumbled over an issue:

How do you table test generic functions?

I came up with this [code](https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/pnqIho7BEe_d), but I need to redeclare my testing logic over each function since I can't instantiate `T` values.
(Inside my project I use structs instead of `string` and `int`. Just didn't want to include them because it's already enough code)

How would you approach this problem?

Edit:
Here's the code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

type Item interface {
    int | string
}

type store[T Item] map[int64]T

// add adds an Item to the map if the id of the Item isn't present already
func (s store[T]) add(key int64, val T) {
    _, exists := s[key]
    if exists {
        return
    }
    s[key] = val
}

func TestStore(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("ints", testInt)
    t.Run("strings", testString)
}

type testCase[T Item] struct {
    name     string
    start    store[T]
    key      int64
    val      T
    expected store[T]
}

func testString(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()
    tests := []testCase[string]{
        {
            name:  "empty map",
            start: store[string]{},
            key:   123,
            val:   "test",
            expected: store[string]{
                123: "test",
            },
        },
        {
            name: "existing key",
            start: store[string]{
                123: "test",
            },
            key: 123,
            val: "newVal",
            expected: store[string]{
                123: "test",
            },
        },
    }
    for _, tc := range tests {
        t.Run(tc.name, runTestCase(tc))
    }
}

func testInt(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()
    tests := []testCase[int]{
        {
            name:  "empty map",
            start: store[int]{},
            key:   123,
            val:   456,
            expected: store[int]{
                123: 456,
            },
        },
        {
            name: "existing key",
            start: store[int]{
                123: 456,
            },
            key: 123,
            val: 999,
            expected: store[int]{
                123: 456,
            },
        },
    }
    for _, tc := range tests {
        t.Run(tc.name, runTestCase(tc))
    }
}

func runTestCase[T Item](tc testCase[T]) func(t *testing.T) {
    return func(t *testing.T) {
        tc.start.add(tc.key, tc.val)
        assert.Equal(t, tc.start, tc.expected)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to systematically test each possible T type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to redeclare my testing logic over each function

Correct.

Your function `runTestCase[T Item](tc testCase[T])` already provides a reasonable level of abstraction. As you did, you can put there some common logic about starting the test and verifying the expected outcome. However that's about it.

A generic type (or function) under test has to be instantiated with some concrete type sooner or later, and one single test table can only include either one of those types — or `interface{}`/`any`, which you can not use to satisfy a specific constraint like `int | string`.

**However, you do not need to always test every possible type parameter. The purpose of generics is to write code that works with arbitrary types**, and in particular the purpose of constraints is to write code with arbitrary types *that support the same operations*.

I'd advise to write unit tests for different types only if the code makes use of operators that have different meanings. For example:

- the `+` operator for numbers (sum) and strings (concatenation)
- the `<` and `>` for numbers (greater, lesser) and strings (lexicographically before or after)

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69772512) where the OP was attempting to do something similar

Comment: Also, "impossible" statements such as `(a > b) == (a <= b)` will never be true for integer values, but can be true for floats due to [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Comparison_with_NaN) values.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can avoid writing separate functions for each type allowed by `T`, if you use `any`(or `interface{}`) to define the test cases, but this comes with the cost of added complexity in the test runner, where you have to assert the type passed through the empty interface before being able to call `add()`.

Just because it is possible doesn't mean it's also better and I have a couple personal thoughts about this:

- *KISS* is a always a good principle
- apart from asserting the expected results, the unit tests may also serve as a piece of documentation for other developers, in terms of edge cases and how  the function is behaving given certain inputs so keeping the code clean is desirable.

On the other hand, there may be scenarios in which, using the approach I wrote below, may be more convenient: imagine you must feed a lot of **real** data into the function, so you end up capturing thousands of real requests which have mixed `int` and `string` inputs for the generic function you want to test. In such a scenario it could be easier to deserialize the captured requests into a slice of test cases that have empty interface members.

```golang
func TestStore(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("testAny", testAny)
}

type testCaseAny struct {
    name     string
    start    any
    key      int64
    val      any
    expected any
}

func testAny(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()
    tests := []testCaseAny{
        {
            name:  "empty map int",
            start: store[int]{},
            key:   123,
            val:   456,
            expected: store[int]{
                123: 456,
            },
        },
        {
            name: "existing key int",
            start: store[int]{
                123: 456,
            },
            key: 123,
            val: 999,
            expected: store[int]{
                123: 456,
            },
        },
        {
            name:  "empty map string",
            start: store[string]{},
            key:   123,
            val:   "test",
            expected: store[string]{
                123: "test",
            },
        },
        {
            name: "existing key string",
            start: store[string]{
                123: "test",
            },
            key: 123,
            val: "newVal",
            expected: store[string]{
                123: "test",
            },
        },
    }
    for _, tc := range tests {
        t.Run(tc.name, runTestCaseAny(tc))
    }
}

func runTestCaseAny(tc testCaseAny) func(t *testing.T) {
    return func(t *testing.T) {
        storeInt, ok := tc.start.(store[int])
        if ok {
            valInt, ok := tc.val.(int)
            assert.True(t, ok) // here we're actually testing the test case, not the add() function
            storeInt.add(tc.key, valInt)
            assert.Equal(t, tc.start, tc.expected)
            return
        }
        storeStr, ok := tc.start.(store[string])
        if ok {
            valStr, ok := tc.val.(string)
            assert.True(t, ok)
            storeStr.add(tc.key, valStr)
            assert.Equal(t, tc.start, tc.expected)
            return
        }
        assert.True(t, false) // fail the test if neither store[int] nor store[string] matched the type
    }
}
```