# return union type in Golang

Tags: go

I want to try the union type implementation in Golang as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69777436/5156096)
I try this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

type intOrString interface {
    int | string
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(measure())

}
func measure[T intOrString]() T {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    min := 20
    max := 35
    temp := rand.Intn(max-min+1) + min

    switch {
    case temp < 20:
        return "low" //'"low"' (type string) cannot be represented by the type T
    case temp > 20:
        return T("high") //Cannot convert an expression of the type 'string' to the type 'T'
    default:
        return T(temp)

    }
}
```

so how I can convert an expression of the type 'string' or 'int' to the type 'T'.

Comment: Even the last case 'return T(temp)' will not compile

Comment: Note that a *union constraint element* is not a *union type*, it's just a "constraint element". Of course constraint elements are fancy words for types, but at the same time, they're not just types, as you can see from this little bit of craziness. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstand how generics work. For your function you must provide a type when you call the function. Like `fmt.Println(measure[string]())`, so in this case you expect to get a `string` from it. If you call it like `measure[int]()` then you expect an int as a result. But you cannot call it without a type parameter. Generics are for function which share the same logic for different types.

For what you want, you must use `any` as a result, then check it if it's a string or an int. Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    res := measure()
    if v, ok := res.(int); ok {
        fmt.Printf("The temp is an int with value %v", v)
    }
    if v, ok := res.(string); ok {
        fmt.Printf("The temp is a string with value %v", v)
    }
}

func measure() any {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    min := 20
    max := 35
    temp := rand.Intn(max-min+1) + min

    switch {
    case temp < 20:
        return "low"
    case temp > 20:
        return "high"
    default:
        return temp
    }
}
```

Or if you want to just print it out (and don't need to know the type), you don't even need to check it, just call `fmt.Printf("The temp is %v", res)`.

Comment: Awesome, how I add restriction so the function return only string or int?

Comment: You can't restrict it. Maybe add a comment before the func, so the linter will tell the coder who will use it.

Comment: thanks, now I understand I can't use union constraint as a return element.