# Using Go interface with diffrent return type

Tags: go, generics, interface

I’ve some function that are doing some of identical logic and I wanted to define a interface, the trick here that the return structure are different, is there any nice way to do it in  Go 1.18.x, or other clean option ...

e.g

```
func AzureRaw(edge v1alpha1.Edge) (*azurev1alpha1.ZtmConfig, error) {
    infra := &azurev1alpha1.ZtmConfig{}
      .....
    return infra, nil
}

func AzureCVE(edge v1alpha1.ETS) (*azurev1alpha1.VrmConfig, error) {
    ctrlPlaneCfg := &azurev1alpha1.VrmConfig{}
    ....
    return ctrlPlaneCfg, nil
}


func GCPRaw(edge v1alpha1.Edge) (*gcpv1alpha1.ZtmConfig, error) {
    infra := &gcpv1alpha1.ZtmConfig{}
      .....
    return infra, nil
}

func GCPCVE(edge v1alpha1.ETS) (*gcpv1alpha1.VrmConfig, error) {
    ctrlPlaneCfg := &gcpv1alpha1.VrmConfig{}
    ....
    return ctrlPlaneCfg, nil
}
```

I've tried Using `T` like following which doesnt works, any idea?

```
type Raw[T any] interface {
    V() T
    CVE() T
}


func (edge v1alpha1.Edge)V() (*azurev1alpha1.ZtmConfig, error) {
    infra := &azurev1alpha1.ZtmConfig{}
      .....
    return infra, nil
}

func (edge v1alpha1.ETS)CVE() (*azurev1alpha1.VrmConfig, error) {
    ctrlPlaneCfg := &azurev1alpha1.VrmConfig{}
    ....
    return ctrlPlaneCfg, nil
}


func (edge v1alpha1.Edge)V() (*gcpv1alpha1.ZtmConfig, error) {
    infra := &gcpv1alpha1.ZtmConfig{}
      .....
    return infra, nil
}

func (edge v1alpha1.ETS)CVE() (*gcpv1alpha1.VrmConfig, error) {
    ctrlPlaneCfg := &gcpv1alpha1.VrmConfig{}
    ....
    return ctrlPlaneCfg, nil
}
```

In the following post they are providing solution for 2 types
[Go Generics - Unions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69772512/go-generics-unions)
However I need something more flexible as I've about 5 different types

Comment: You can add as many types as you want in a union. `T1 | T2 | T3 | …`

Comment: Also, after declaring it, you have to actually use that union to constrain a type parameter, instead of `any`, as shown in the very first snippet of the linked answer

Comment: @blackgreen - Not sure I got it, I need the type to be flexbilie in the return, should I do it like this `type ProvRaw interface {
 azurev1alpha1.ZtmConfig | gcpv1alpha1.ZtmConfig

}
` ? as it doesnt work for me ...

Comment: Something like that, yes. Then after declaring the union constraint you have to actually use it

Comment: @blackgreen - I've tried like following but didnt figure out how to call it, can you please have a look https://go.dev/play/p/xsqlT2i0-A9

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/TATbG8IpCtN This is a basic example. If you need to use it in a method instead, you can declare generic types with that constraint.